# Woocommerce variation price product total based on quantity

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a total price on a product page based on quantity.  What is the best way to add a total price on the product page with variations?

On simple product pages this code works. But it does not work with variations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    
    $data['price_html'] = '<div id="subtot" style="display:inline-block;">Total:<span></span></div>';
    
   $price = $variation->get_price();

   $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
   wc_enqueue_js( "      
 
    
      $('[name=quantity]').on('input change', function() { 
         var qty = $(this).val();
                
        
         var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
         
            if (!(qty < 1)) {
            
                        if (qty < 4){
                            var price_string = price * qty;
                        }
                        if (qty >= 4){
                            var price_string = price * qty * 0.95;      
                        }
                        if(qty > 9){
                            var price_string = price * qty * 0.90;          
                        }
                    }
                    

         $('#subtot > span').html('" . esc_js( $currency ) . "'+price_string);
      }).change();
   " );
 
    return $data;
}
```

https://gyazo.com/acecac1589c5932039549fb5846502b5

[The variation price shows and changes so maybe i can use javascript to get this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6hsu.png)